# Beau, my dear friend, who we remember here today

Tags: grammar

Does "my dear friend" refer back to "Beau"?

It’s his love for Jill, who will be an incredible first lady.

It’s his love for Hunter, Ashley, his grandchildren, and the entire Biden family.

And while I first knew Joe as Vice President, I really got to know him as the father who loved **Beau, my dear friend, who we remember here today**.

To my husband Doug, our children Cole and Ella, my sister Maya, and our whole family — I love you all more than I can express.

Source:  [Kamala Harris's Victory Speech in Full](https://www.esquire.com/news-politics/a34608824/kamala-harris-victory-speech-full-transcript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it is ambiguous, the obvious meaning is that "My dear friend" does refer to Beau.  However, Kamala Harris is known to have been a friend of Beau Biden. So it the meaning is clear.